# Why I can't receive APDU buffer contents?

Tags: smartcard, javacard, apdu, contactless-smartcard

I wrote the following program to return all the APDU buffer contents on reception of each APDU command:

```
package testPack;

import javacard.framework.APDU;
import javacard.framework.Applet;
import javacard.framework.ISOException;

public class BufferReturner extends Applet {

    private BufferReturner() {
    }

    public static void install(byte bArray[], short bOffset, byte bLength) throws ISOException {
        new BufferReturner().register();
    }

    public void process(APDU arg0) throws ISOException {
        if(selectingApplet()){
            return;
        }
        arg0.setOutgoingAndSend((short)0, (short)255);

    }

}
```

When I send commands though the contact interface using `T=0` protocol, I receive the following result:

```
Connect successful.
Send: 00 A4 04 00 06 01 02 03 04 05 00 00
Recv: 90 00
Time used: 8.000 ms
Send: 00 00 00 00 10 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 00
Send Apdu error: A device attached to the system is not functioning.
Send: 00 00 00 00 10 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 00
Recv: 6C FF
Time used: 5.000 ms
Send: 00 00 00 00 10 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 FF
Recv: 6C FF
Time used: 5.000 ms
Send: 00 00 00 00 10 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 FF
Recv: 6C FF
Time used: 5.000 ms
Send: 00 00 00 00 10 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 FF
Recv: 6C FF
Time used: 6.000 ms
Send: 00 C0 00 00 FF
Send Apdu error: A device attached to the system is not functioning.
Send: 00 C0 00 00 FF
Send Apdu error: A device attached to the system is not functioning.
```

As you see I can't receive the APDU buffer contents. What's wrong?

Comment: Did you try the Get Response APDU to receive data for T=0 ? And can you please check the return code of `apdu.setIncomingAndReceive()`

Comment: @PaulBastian Dear Paul, I modified the question.The previous was wrong.-- As you see, I tried Get Response command also, but it didn't helped. (And there is no `setIncommingAndReceive()` method in this program).

Comment: You need `apdu.setIncomingAndReceive()` to get the `11`s into the APDU buffer.

Comment: Did you try sending a smaller number than 255? Maybe your cards buffer isnt big enough. And also try not sending a case4 command but simply with Le and no data.

Comment: @PaulBastian, When I add `apdu.setIncomingAndReceive()` everything works fine(Both in `T=0` and `T=1`). So APDU buffer length is OK. When I remove `apdu.setIncomingAndReceive()` line, In `T=1` output is correct (All is zero because I didn't received the data), but in `T=0` output is as above and it is not as I expect.

Comment: My guess its an internal error, because the card expects `apdu.setIncomingAndReceive()`, because it knows its a case4 command. And because you don't implement it, the card probably is in a false state because it cannot call `apdu.setOutgoing` before the incoming part is finished. Your T=1 NXP JCOP card is just more relaxed on this issue and continues working

Comment: @PaulBastian This card is dual interface. Its contact interface working with `T=0` protocol and have above problem, while its contactless interface working `T=1` and doesn't have the above issue.

Comment: Ok, debug by checking your internal state with `apdu.getCurrentState()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like with [Transmission error for T=0 JavaCards](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34986522/2425802) there is nothing wrong with your card and this is kind of "expected" behavior.

For the `setOutgoing()` method (`setOutgoingAndSend()` is just a convenience method wrapping `setOutgoing()`), the Java Card API specification clearly states:

> On a case 4 command, the `setIncomingAndReceive()` must be invoked prior to calling this method. Otherwise, erroneous behavior may result in T=0 protocol.

Hence, what you see is exactly that "*erroneous behavior*" indicated in the API specification.